# how to replace the variable in javascript with the angularjs result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I create the search suggestion function in html which is in javascrip.

in the app.js (angular), by using http get: I got the json data from URL and store in $scope.JSONresult.

I would like to replace the list in html:

```
['b0','b12','b22','b3','b4','b5','b6','b7','b8','b2','abd','ab','acd','accd','b1','cd','ccd','cbcv','cxf']
```

with `{{JSONresult.relevantWord}}`

below is the sample code.

html and normal javascript:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<style> 
body { 
margin-left: 0px; 
margin-top: 0px; 
margin-right: 0px; 
margin-bottom: 0px; 
} 
.auto_hidden { 
width:204px;border-top: 1px solid #333; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #333; 
border-left: 1px solid #333; 
border-right: 1px solid #333; 
position:absolute; 
display:none; 
} 
.auto_show { 
width:204px; 
border-top: 1px solid #333; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #333; 
border-left: 1px solid #333; 
border-right: 1px solid #333; 
position:absolute; 
z-index:9999; 
display:block; 
} 
.auto_onmouseover{ 
color:#ffffff; 
background-color:highlight; 
width:100%; 
} 
.auto_onmouseout{ 
color:#000000; 
width:100%; 
background-color:#ffffff; 
} 
</style> 
<script language="javascript"> 
<!-- 
var $ = function (id) { 
return "string" == typeof id ? document.getElementById(id) : id; 
} 
var Bind = function(object, fun) { 
return function() { 
return fun.apply(object, arguments); 
} 
} 
function AutoComplete(obj,autoObj,arr){ 
this.obj=$(obj); // 
this.autoObj=$(autoObj);//  
this.value_arr=arr; // 
this.index=-1; //  
this.search_value=""; // 
} 
AutoComplete.prototype={ 
//  
init: function(){ 
this.autoObj.style.left = this.obj.offsetLeft + "px"; 
this.autoObj.style.top = this.obj.offsetTop + this.obj.offsetHeight + "px"; 
this.autoObj.style.width= this.obj.offsetWidth - 2 + "px";//  
}, 
//  
deleteDIV: function(){ 
while(this.autoObj.hasChildNodes()){ 
this.autoObj.removeChild(this.autoObj.firstChild); 
} 
this.autoObj.className="auto_hidden"; 
}, 
// 
setValue: function(_this){ 
return function(){ 
_this.obj.value=this.seq; 
_this.autoObj.className="auto_hidden"; 
} 
}, 
//  
autoOnmouseover: function(_this,_div_index){ 
return function(){ 
_this.index=_div_index; 
var length = _this.autoObj.children.length; 
for(var j=0;j<length;j++){ 
if(j!=_this.index ){ 
_this.autoObj.childNodes[j].className='auto_onmouseout'; 
}else{ 
_this.autoObj.childNodes[j].className='auto_onmouseover'; 
} 
} 
} 
}, 
// change classname 
changeClassname: function(length){ 
for(var i=0;i<length;i++){ 
if(i!=this.index ){ 
this.autoObj.childNodes[i].className='auto_onmouseout'; 
}else{ 
this.autoObj.childNodes[i].className='auto_onmouseover'; 
this.obj.value=this.autoObj.childNodes[i].seq; 
} 
} 
} 
, 
// 
pressKey: function(event){ 
var length = this.autoObj.children.length; 
// 
if(event.keyCode==40){ 
++this.index; 
if(this.index>length){ 
this.index=0; 
}else if(this.index==length){ 
this.obj.value=this.search_value; 
} 
this.changeClassname(length); 
} 
// 
else if(event.keyCode==38){ 
this.index--; 
if(this.index<-1){ 
this.index=length - 1; 
}else if(this.index==-1){ 
this.obj.value=this.search_value; 
} 
this.changeClassname(length); 
} 
// 
else if(event.keyCode==13){ 
this.autoObj.className="auto_hidden"; 
this.index=-1; 
}else{ 
this.index=-1; 
} 
}, 
// 
start: function(event){ 
if(event.keyCode!=13&&event.keyCode!=38&&event.keyCode!=40){ 
this.init(); 
this.deleteDIV(); 
this.search_value=this.obj.value; 
var valueArr=this.value_arr; 
valueArr.sort(); 
if(this.obj.value.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/g,'')==""){ return; } 
try{ var reg = new RegExp("(" + this.obj.value + ")","i");} 
catch (e){ return; } 
var div_index=0; 
for(var i=0;i<valueArr.length;i++){ 
if(reg.test(valueArr[i])){ 
var div = document.createElement("div"); 
div.className="auto_onmouseout"; 
div.seq=valueArr[i]; 
div.onclick=this.setValue(this); 
div.onmouseover=this.autoOnmouseover(this,div_index); 
div.innerHTML=valueArr[i].replace(reg,"<strong>$1</strong>"); 
this.autoObj.appendChild(div); 
this.autoObj.className="auto_show"; 
div_index++; 
} 
} 
} 
this.pressKey(event); 
window.onresize=Bind(this,function(){this.init();}); 
} 
} 
//--> 
</script> 
<body> 
<div align="center" style="padding-top:50px"> 
<input type="text" style="width:300px;height:20px;font-size:14pt;" placeholder="please enter a or b " id="o" onkeyup="autoComplete.start(event)"> 
</div> 
<div class="auto_hidden" id="auto"><!--finish DIV--></div> 
<script> 
var autoComplete=new AutoComplete('o','auto',['b0','b12','b22','b3','b4','b5','b6','b7','b8','b2','abd','ab','acd','accd','b1','cd','ccd','cbcv','cxf']); 
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

app.js (angualrjs)

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('siteCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("http://www.xxxx.com/try/angularjs/data/sites.php")
      .success(function (response) {
       $scope.JSONresult = response.sites;});
    });
```

json data:

```
{ "relevantWord": ["Lighthouse", "family", "house", "national Ranking", "national Years", "national Selection", "carbohydrate", "national Affiliation", "home Arena", "max Absolute Magnitude", "premiere Place", "automobile Model", "notable Commander", "intercommunality", "inhabitants Per Square Kilometre", "home Colour Hex Code", "inhabitants Per Square Mile", "cambodian Riel", "homage", "maiden Voyage"],
"namelist": ["123", "334", "4234"]
}
```

to replace

```
<script> 
var autoComplete=new AutoComplete('o','auto',{{JSONresult.relevantWord}}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to display a list containing all the items? Use `ng-repeat` for that.

Comment: i edit my question

Answer (score 0):

Sorry If I didn't get what you want to do.
You can try to change autoComplete in your success:

`autoComplete = new AutoComplete('o','auto',response.sites.relevantWord);`

Comment: Do you want to change `autoComplete` or you wanna change html itself? if you wanna change your `autoComplete` variable you need to execute the script. just replacing script tag content doesn't change anything

Comment: You can do this `autoComplete=new AutoComplete('o','auto',$scope.JSONresult.relevantWord); ` in success